# erro de concatenação ao instanciar PDO

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho a **conexão** `PDO` com `mysql` abaixo:

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::$hostname . '; dbname=' . self::$dbname;
 $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');

 self::$conexao = new PDO( 
                              $dsn,
                              self::$username, 
                              self::$password, 
                              $opcoes
                          );
```

que funciona perfeitamente.

Mas se eu colocar o conteúdo da **variável** `$dsn` junto à **string** de **conexão** conforme abaixo dá **erro** que me parece ser de **concatenação**.

Alguém por favor me ajuda a descobrir onde está esse erro?

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');

 self::$conexao = new PDO( "mysql:
                              host=" . self::$hostname . "; 
                              dbname=" . self::$dbname,
                              self::$username, 
                              self::$password, 
                              $opcoes
                          );
```

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não é possível ter quebras de linha no DSN.

Comment: resolveu o problema?

Comment: sim. já até aceitei a resposta abaixo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que seja da quebra de linha.
tenta assim:

```
new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$hostname.";dbname=". self::$dbname, self::$username, self::$password, $opcoes);
```

Comment: já tentei assim antes e também não funcionou!

Comment: é, de fato, eu estava colocando a quebra de linha em todos parâmetros. Quando coloquei apenas nos 2 últimos, aí funcionou. Obrigado!